# How can I redirect to a specific component after successful Google Authentication?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

Currently when I click on the `Google Sign In` link via the `Home.js` file, I get redirected to an empty screen via a URL that looks like this `http://localhost:8000/auth/google?code=4%2F0AbUR2VMUl1Whgx6U7cbRIROFQ-Ftfbq4U5OxI4ytlMCsjENSCWQyTHNwun6HaSmWog&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid&authuser=0&prompt=none`

I also see no errors in the console and Network tab.  In fact, nothing gets logged in console and nothing shows up in the network tab upon redirection to the above link.

I'm confused on what's going on.  How can I modify my code so it that redirects to the `/gallery` component when authenticated with google auth?

Home.js:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    };

    ApiClient.get('/auth', {headers})
        .then((response) => {
            setLoginUrl(response.data.url);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("error",error);
    });
}, []);

<div>
  {loginUrl !== null && (<a href={loginUrl}>Google Sign In</a>)}
</div>
```

AuthController.php:

```
public function redirectToAuth()
{
    return response()->json([
        'url' => Socialite::driver('google')
            ->stateless()
            ->redirect()
            ->getTargetUrl(),
    ]);
}

public function handleAuthCallback()
{
    try {
        $socialiteUser = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
    } catch (ClientException $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid credentials provided.'], 422);
    }

    /** @var User $user */
    $user = User::query()
        ->firstOrCreate(
            [
                'email' => $socialiteUser->getEmail(),
            ],
            [
                'email_verified_at' => now(),
                'name' => $socialiteUser->getName(),
                'google_id' => $socialiteUser->getId(),
                'avatar' => $socialiteUser->getAvatar(),
            ]
        );

    return response()->json([
        'user' => $user,
        'access_token' => $user->createToken('google-token')->plainTextToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
    ]);
}
```

GoogleCallback.js:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
import ApiClient from "../utilities/ApiClient";

function GoogleCallback() {

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const location = useLocation();

    // On page load, we take "search" parameters
    // and proxy them to /api/auth/callback on our Laravel API
    useEffect(() => {

        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        };

        ApiClient.get(`/auth/callback${location.search}`, {headers})
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("response GoogleCallback.js",response);
                setLoading(false);
                setData(data);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, []);

    // Helper method to fetch User data for authenticated user
    // Watch out for "Authorization" header that is added to this call
    function fetchUserData() {
        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + data.access_token,
        };

        console.log(headers);

        ApiClient.get(`/user`, {headers})
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                setUser(data);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
        });
    }

    if (loading) {
        return <DisplayLoading/>
    } else {
        if (user != null) {
            return <DisplayData data={user}/>
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <DisplayData data={data}/>
                    <div style={{marginTop:10}}>
                        <button onClick={fetchUserData}>Fetch User</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

function DisplayLoading() {
    return <div>Loading....</div>;
}

function DisplayData(data) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>test</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default GoogleCallback;
```

ProtectedRoute.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const ProtectedRoute = (props) =>  {
    const user = localStorage.getItem('token'); // this holding the Laravel sanctum token, not the Google auth token

    if(!user) {
        return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }

    return <Route {...props} />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./Home/Home";
import GoogleCallback from "./GoogleCallback";
import Grid from "./Grid/Grid";

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/auth/google" element={<GoogleCallback/>}></Route>
                <ProtectedRoute path="/gallery" component={Grid} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

const container = document.getElementById('example');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<UserProvider><App/></UserProvider>);
```

Comment: did you solve this?